# How to put three thin pages in a A4 page PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing

I would like to convert [this manual](http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/GY300_Dtype_E.pdf) into a PDF that is easier to print with standard A4 paper and printers.

The pages in the manual are very thin: 74 × 140 mm (W×H), much smaller than a A4 page (whose dimensions are 210 × 297 mm). I would like to have three of them on a A4 page in landscape orientation. Here is a drawing:

```
        manual pages
      /      |      \
.----V-------V-------V----. 
|.~~~~~~~.~~~~~~~.~~~~~~~.| <- A4 page
||  pag  |  pag  |  pag  ||
||       |       |       ||
||   1   |   2   |   3   ||
|`~~~~~~~'~~~~~~~'~~~~~~~'|
`-------------------------'
```

I tried using the "print on multiple pages" functionality of evince and okular, but to no avail: they do not allow an odd number of pages to be merged in a single printed page, only powers of two.

How can I generate a PDF where the original thin pages assembled to so have three of them in a A4 page in landscape orientation?

Comment: Any chance to use `LibreOffice Writer` to compose a landscape page with text arranged in three columns (`Format->Page`, `Format->Columns`) and then perform `File->Export as PDF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `nup` feature of `pdfjam`

```
pdfjam --a4paper --landscape --nup 3x1 --outfile out.pdf GY300_Dtype_E.pdf
```

(tested with pdfjam version 2.08 on Ubuntu). Some systems may provide separate a `pdfnup` executable - AFAIK the command syntax is the same.

[PDFjam README](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/)